# Connecting to a UDP data stream with Mathematica

Tags: udp, wolfram-mathematica

I have an app on my iPhone called [iSeismometer](http://www.iseismometer.com/) which reads the iPhone's accelerometers and acts as a server which streams this data via UDP (I can set the IP address and port number). The question is how to read this data stream with Mathematica? Apparently, [Dreeves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4234/dreeves) has been looking into this [12 years ago](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/May/msg00104.html), so I imagine something must have happened in the meantime.

**Update**
I got two great answers so far; one from WReach and one from Mark McClure. Both are using JLink to get at the data. This seems like a fine approach. However, I was reminded of some work I did on the WII balance board. Using a few free programs (GlovePIE and PPJoy) I got this bluetooth peripheral to appear as a joystick to Windows, and therefore also to Mathematica (via `ControllerState`). Of course, bluetooth and UDP are quite different, but could something along the same lines be made to work too?

Comment: I suppose none of the suggestions in that thread work for you, right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seemed to deal with TCP instead of UDP, also involving MathLink with which I'm not too familiar, using code for a different platform (Unix/Solaris), based on old versions of mma. Frankly, it looked like too much work. As there might be comfortable packages written since, I thought it better to await suggestions first.

Comment: My question may have seemed to imply that you should look to that thread for solutions, but that was not my intention.  Rather, I just wanted to confirm that posting a version of one of the replies to that thread would not be appreciated.  I guess that could be assumed, and therefore my question was pointless. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problemo. BTW, a quiet day, don't you think?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are wrong. Dreeves was surely too young 12 years ago. Should be an homonym.

Comment: I think you may set up a server like this one http://www.iseismometer.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/receiver.zip to read the data from the UDP port and write it to a named pipe. Then read the named pipe from Mma as a Stream

Comment: @Sjoerd retagged a question as Mma, just for breaking the boring afternoon

Comment: Maybe you could write something that uses JLink?

Comment: @belisarius If I follow the links it looks like the same Daniel Reeves all the way. Perhaps he's older than you think.

Comment: How did he manage to have an iPhone 12 years ago?

Comment: @belisarius I noticed this python app but didn't have a clear idea how this thing printing to a console window would bring the data nearer to mma. No python user either, so it seemed a bit a dead end.

Comment: @belisarius Windows 7 - 64 bit

Comment: @TomD Obviously, dreeves' Mathgroup thread of 12 years ago just dealt with reading sockets, not in an iPhone context.

Comment: @brett JLink is one of the blind spots that I have in mma. Do you have suggestions how to approach this without having to learn both java and JLink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JLink is definitely the way to go.  I prefer to keep my Java code and my Mathematica code separate by compiling a Java programwhich I then call from Mathematica.  I set up a Notebook and companion Java program that you can grab here:
http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/UDPFiles.tar.gz

Here is the essential Mathematica code:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
udpReader = JavaNew["myClient"];
i = 0;
While[True && i++ < 100,
  Print[udpReader@udpReadOne[10552]]]
```

The updReader class is defined by the following Java code.

```
// A simple UDP client to read from iseismometer:
// http://www.iseismometer.com/
// You can run this from the command line via "java myClient"
// to check that your iseismometer setup is correct or you can
// call the the udpReadOne method from another program.

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myClient {
    public static void main() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(10552);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while(true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            System.out.println(received);
        }
    }

    public static String udpReadOne(int port) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        socket.close();
        return received;
    }
}
```

Note that you can use the main method of the myClient class to check that your setup is working without Mathematica, essentially taking one potential issue out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Mark! See also my comments @WReach. Difficult to determine which is the best solution. Both work great to make a live graph of the data coming in. It looks like yours is somewhat easier to use if you'd like to read more iPhones at the same time, whereas WReach's is self-contained in mma and doesn't require messing with external java stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the set-up discussed in a [blog entry](http://www.iseismometer.com/tutorial/how-to-transmit-signals-via-wi-fi/) on the iSeismometer web site, a couple of options come to mind.

**Import**

The first option would be to use an external program to capture the packets, and then use `Import` to bring in the results, e.g.

```
Import["!someexternalprog", "Lines"]
```

Alas, the Python program mentioned in the blog post will not work well here since it runs in an endless loop that must be manually terminated.  The `Import` approach would only work if that program were modified to stop after a fixed number of packets or a time limit or something.

**JLink**

An alternate approach can be implemented without leaving the comfy Mathematica environment by using JLink.  Well, perhaps it is a stretch to say that we are staying within Mathematica since a fair amount of funny-looking Java code is mixed in with the Mathematica code.  Nevertheless, it does illustrate the utility of the built-in Java distribution that ships with every copy of Mathematica:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
LoadJavaClass["java.util.Arrays"];

ClearAll@ListenToISeismometer
ListenToISeismometer[port_] :=
  JavaBlock@Module[{socket, packet, listen, record = Null, listening = True}
  , packet = JavaNew["java.net.DatagramPacket", JavaNew["[B", 1024], 1024]
  ; listen[] :=
      If[$Failed =!= Quiet[socket@receive[packet], Java::excptn]
      , record =
          JavaNew[
            "java.lang.String"
          , java`util`Arrays`copyOfRange @@ packet /@ {getData[], getOffset[], getLength[]}
          ]@toString[] // Sow
      ]
  ; Row[{Button["Stop", listening = False], Dynamic[record]}, "  "] // PrintTemporary
  ; AbortProtect[
      socket = JavaNew["java.net.DatagramSocket", port]
    ; socket@setSoTimeout[1000]
    ; Reap[While[listening, listen[]]; socket@close[]][[2, 1]]
    ]
  ]
```

Some shortcuts have been taken with respect to exception handling, packet decoding and the like in order to keep this example at a manageable length.

`ListenToISeismometer` needs to be given the UDP port number to listen upon.  Let's use the same port as in the blog post, 10552:

```
In[33]:= data = ListenToISeismometer[10552];
```

[image: stop button]

The function will listen to all UDP events on that port until told to stop.  A button is presented for this purpose, with each packet flashing by along side as received.
When the button is pressed, the function returns a list of the packets received:

```
In[34]:= data // Column
Out[34]= 1,83575.099,0.029,0.044,0.094
         1,83575.781,0.056,0.033,0.099
         1,83575.924,0.047,0.054,0.094
         1,83575.613,0.096,0.092,0.057
         1,83575.748,0.073,0.049,0.061
         1,83575.577,0.008,0.089,0.020
         ...
```

JLink makes this *possible*, but there is no escaping the fact that the use of JLink requires a working knowledge of Java.

Comment: Thanks! This is easily adaptable to show a live graph of the 3 accelerometer channels. Using an array with 400 data points and a bit of `RotateLeft` with the most recent data in the last position gets my a nice floating graph. I noticed a bit of lag which seems to be growing over time. A read/write buffer that is written faster than it is read? I don't think you can have more than one instance of `ListenToISeismometer` running, can you? If that would be possible, I could use my wive's iPhone and our iPad to see how the waves of the nearby railroad construction travel through our house.

Comment: @Sjoerd ListenToISeismometer won't support multiple instances as written.  The blog entry has a screenshot that shows a "broadcast" button in ISeismometer -- perhaps it supports UDP multicast?  If so, ListenToISeismometer would have to be changed to use multicast sockets.  There are more direct ways to speed up packet throughput by using different Java API, but I'm not sure whether I would try that through JLink.  I would probably push most of the logic into a regular Java class, as in @Mark's solution.